# Deleting column based on screen size

Tags: mysql, html, css

I have a Python program that uses `mod_python` to retrieve database entries from MySQL and display them in an HTML format. This webpage ends up as a table with four columns, that span the entire page. (I formatted it with CSS)

Is it possible to use CSS to change the number of colums if the screen width is under a certain number of pixels? One of these four columns have a large amount of info in it, and it is not idea for viewing it on a mobile screen. The text appears small and hard to read, and zooming in is not convenient either. I want to know, is it possible to use css or something else to remove this column if the screen size is smaller than say, 800px? So on an iPhone 3g, the table would show with only three columns instead of four on a larger screen. This would make the text easier to read on the go.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is, and quite easily. You can do it using media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { your styles here }
```

So in your case, your css would have the style for the column, something like `.column4 {display:block;}`, and after that your media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 

   .column4 {
       display:none;
   }

}
```

You can have different queries for different screen sizes (in my latest project I used 6 different layouts, for 6 different resolutions and devices). Add some percentages to that and you can have a really nice responsive site.

Comment: that`s what I was looking for. Thanks!